# Would problems arise if a domain was bought as 'name.com' instead of 'www.name.com'

Tags: domains

If a website domain name was bought and registered as 'name.com' instead of '**www**.name.com' would users still be able to find the site by typing 'www.name.com'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't purchase "www.name.com" from a TLD (top-level domain) registrar; you can only purchase name.com, and then the DNS servers for name.com would be responsible for handling the www. portion.

Answer (score 7):

www.name.com isn't a domain it is a hostname/subdomain derived from name.com.

The domain, is `name.com`.

So what you have asked is not possible.

If you had a domain name.com you would configure an Alias so that your website also accepts requests from www.name.com and then you would make sure using a 301 redirect that all requests are routed to either the www.name.com version or the name.com.